# The cohomology of $\mathrm{GL}_n$ over an algebraically closed field

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, group-cohomology

How does one go about computing the cohomology groups $H^*(\mathrm{GL}_{\kern{0.1em}{m}}(\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p),M)$? I am particularly interested in the case when $M$ is an algebraic representation. I would also like to avoid assuming that $p$ is very big compared to $m$. One example of interest: $M$ is the adjoint representation of dimension $m^2$.

Comment: Do you assume some topology on the group ?

Comment: Since $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$ is naturally discrete, I can't imagine what topology you would put on this group.

Comment: It's an algebraic group, si it has at least the Zariski topology.

Comment: From the point of view of group cohomology, that would be a strange choice. It is the discrete topology.